# Как считать повторяющиеся слова кратные числу 3?

Tags: javascript

Нужно узнать сколько раз фраза (опоздание более 15 мин) будет кратна числу 3.

Например в моем коде встречается эта фраза  (опоздание более 15 мин) 6 раз,  в условии у меня написано что если число например 6 == 3 то есть кратно числу 3 то идет счетчик который считает сколько раз эта фраза кратна, получается 2- (6/3=2). 
**Проблема** заключается в том что пользователь может менять строчки, а именно менять фразу (не согласовано) на согласовано и получается что если опоздание согласовано то повторяющихся фраз будет не 6 а 5 т.к. если согласовано опоздание более 15 мин == Согласовано то эта фраза грубо говоря вычитается. И получается что в условии у нас будет так 5 == 3, то есть не кратно 3 и будет 1 - (5/3=1(если округлить без остатка)). 
Мне не хватает логики придумать так чтобы если фраз было не четное количество то значения бы считались.

```js
var k = 0;
 jQuery(function($) {

   //console.log(add());

 });

 function add() {
   $('table tr').each(function(row, e) {

     var col1 = $(e).children('td:nth-child(4)').text();
     var col2 = $(e).children('td:nth-child(5)').text();
     if (col1 == 'опоздание более 15мин' && col2 == 'согласовано') {
       // console.log(col1, col2);
       return ++k;

     }
   });
 }
 add();
 //$('span.r1').text('Позиций согласовано: ' + k);
  //Счетчики для проверки внутри цикла
 var razCounter = 0;
 var dvaCounter = 0;
  //Счетчики для присваивания результата
 var razResultCounter = 0;
 var dvaResultCounter = 0;
  //Выборка всех ячеек таблицы с контентом
 var razArray = document.querySelectorAll("table td");
  //Перебор ячеек
 for (var i = 0; razArray.length > i; i++) {
   var currentContent = razArray[i].innerHTML;
   if (currentContent == "опоздание более 15мин") {
     razCounter++;
     
     if (razCounter == 3) { 
       razResultCounter++;
       razCounter = 0; 
     }
   } else if (currentContent == "опоздание менее 15мин") {
     dvaCounter++;
     if (dvaCounter == 3) {
       dvaResultCounter++;
       dvaCounter = 0;
     }
   }
 }
 $('span.t').text("Более 15 мин кратны числу 3 :           " + razResultCounter); // Это значение важно для расчета, тут показывается число кратное 3
 $('span.t1').text("Менее 15 мин: кратны числу 3:           " + dvaResultCounter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="1020" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
   
    <tr>
      
      <td width="230">опоздание более 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>
      
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     
      <td width="230">опоздание менее 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>

    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      
      <td width="230">опоздание более 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
     
      <td width="230">опоздание менее 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>
      
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     
      <td width="230">опоздание более 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
      <td width="230">опоздание более 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>
      
    </tr>
   
   
    <tr>
     
      <td width="230">опоздание более 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
     
      <td width="230">опоздание более 15мин</td>
      <td width="140">не согласовано</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
 
  </tbody>
</table>
<span class="t"></span>
<br>
<span class="t1"></span>
<br>
<span class="r1"></span>
```

Comment: Вы ведь можете посчитать количество вхождений "опоздание более" и "опоздание менее" для любого количества записей? Всю вашу логику по кратности можно заменить целочисленным делением.

Comment: @br3t, этот код и считает количество вхождений в таблице. Просто у меня мозг взорвался как решить эту задачу. Вроде как и не сложно, но я уже не могу найти сам решение.

Comment: сравнение текстовых строк в логике приложения до добра не доведет. На серверной стороне определите какие строки у вас с опозданием меньше, какие больше, какие согласованы, какие нет. и пометьте их соответствующими атрибутами `data-`. Далее работайте с атрибутами, иначе когда у вас 15 минут превратятся в 10, проклянете тот день когда написали этот код, особенно если его много. Я вам еще в прошлый раз по-моему это советовал.

Comment: @teran, все верно говорите. Просто сроки по проекту очень сильно поджимают и пока оставлю так, но переделать обязуюсь.

Comment: [ловите](https://jsfiddle.net/w3Lmhqhq/1/) может поможет чем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем виде ваша формула будет примерно такой:

```
сounter = Math.floor(lines/3);
```

где `lines` - количество ваших вхождений,

`counter` - это ваша кратность

Comment: На это я наткнулся уже в процессе решения, но как мне связать это с моим кодом что было работало корректно, поможете внедрить это в код JS ? Я просто не спец а новичок и стараюсь, разобраться сам. Но как видите решения я знаю а вот реализовать самому не до конца получается в связи отсутствия опыта.

Comment: Посмотрите, этот код https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/ufgp9ec4/ правильно работает?

Comment: Ошибку консоли выдает в этом месте $(".t").text(Math.floor(lines.more15/3)) на lines ругается.

Comment: Текст ошибки скопировать можете? Заодно `console.log(add())`

Comment: выдает такую ошибку( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'more15' of undefined).

Comment: Значит, вы `add` потеряли

Comment: а еще вопрос, пример работает хорошо. А вот когда пытаюсь перенести в проект то ни чего не работает, я как понимаю нужно указать атрибут children('td:nth-child()') для фраз чтобы понимать откуда они беретуся, children('td:nth-child(8)') - это опоздание более 15мин, children('td:nth-child(9)') - это опоздание менее 15мин

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52627/discussion-between-br3t-and-).